# How do I set Ubuntu as the host grub system?

Tags: grub2

I've installed a couple of other Linux distros on my hard drive, and every time I do grub changes to being installed on the latest installed distro.

How do I change grub back to being installed/configured on Ubuntu? I want my laptop to boot from "ubuntu-grub" and not "arch-grub", "deepin-grub", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the link in muru's answer and that gave me the simple step (that he also has buried in his answer) which simply was:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo update-grub
```

I will also be removing the grub files from the other partitions (or completely deleting said partitions since I'm not really using them right now) to remove the chance of an update messing things up.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the Grub packages from the other distros, since they aren't providing any functionality.Use the appropriate package manager to remove it, then set up a chroot to install Grub from Ubuntu.

To set up a chroot, mount the partition where Ubuntu is installed somewhere (e.g. `/mnt`) and do:

```
sudo mount /dev /mnt/dev -o bind
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do
    sudo mount -B $i /mnt/$i;
done 
sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
# From here on you're in the Ubuntu chroot, logged in as root.
grub-install /dev/sda 
update-grub
exit # exit the chroot
```

Replace `sda` with the appropriate device, which you can look up with `lsblk` - it's the device at the top of the tree. If you have a separate boot partition, you'll need to mount that too, before entering the installing Grub. Do not use `shutdown` or similar commands within the chroot, since `/mnt/proc` is mounted to the real `/proc`, you'll shutdown the base system.

Check http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099 for a detailed guide on reinstalling Grub.